# Function returning reference to object property

Tags: php, reference

I've got an event object that looks like this:

```
class InputEvent
{
    protected $input;

    public function __construct(&$input)
    {
        $this->input = &$input;
    }

    public function getInput()
    {
         return $this->input;
    }
}
```

Now, since `$input` is a string, I have to pass it in by reference. However, when I create an event listener, input value doesn't get changed since `getInput` function returns `$input` value rather than reference to `$input` property.

```
class Listener
{
    public function myEvent(InputEvent $event)
    {
         $input = $event->getInput();

         // doesn't change InputEvent::input property
         $input = "asd";
    }
}
```

Is there a way for me to return reference to `$input` value, so that it gets changed inside event object?

I can make two workarounds, but both are.....well, workarounds, not really pretty.

1. Wrap `$input` into a class, for example creating a `String` class which would only hold value and getter, setter methods.
2. Add `setInput` method to `InputEvent`, but still isn't as elegant as just assigning it to a value like in `Listener` example above.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

Comment: @moonwave99 I will if I have no other choice, but since some events will return objects and won't need setters, it might create confusion for end-developers.

Comment: @Jon Sadly, I've read the documentation. adding `&getInput()` doesn't help.

Comment: Even if you have `function &getInput()` you still need to do `$input = &$event->getInput();`

Comment: But what's the point in not using a setter? If you don't need it, you just don't call it - as a latest resort, consider using a [magic setter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set).

Comment: It doesn't have obvious downsides. I could have as well just made `$input` public property. I'm just used to making Event objects more like 'packages' carrying references to stuff and rolling down the road allowing listeners to change them so I don't like using any methods except getters. I'm weird, I know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As moonwave99 mentioned above, you'll need to use a setter. In your InputEvent class add the  method:

```
public function setInput(&$s) {
    $this->input = $s;
}
```

Or you could return a reference:

```
public function &getInputRef() {
    return $this->input;
}
$input = &$event->getInputRef();
```

Which I think should work the same.

Comment: Works now! Seems strange to me though that I need to use reference sign both in function definition __and__ value assignment lines.

Comment: Be glad you never had to deal with pointers to arrays of pointers in C then ;)

Comment: I'm too young for C! :) I have never touched anything further than C++, and even then I had huge trouble dealing with pointers and references in general.

Answer (score 0):

Have your getInput function return by reference

```
function &getInput()
         ^-- signifies return value by reference
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I've tried it.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6d6115d208b7cd02d84c6b47fd71a47d4ab9c738

Comment: As runspired says above, you'll still need `$input =& $event->getInput();` in your myEvent method

Comment: Yeah, didn't realize I have to do that too.

Answer (score 0):

```
class InputEvent
{
    protected $input;

    public function __construct(&$input)
    {
        $this->input = $input;
    }

    public function &getInput()
    {
        return $this->input;
    }
}
$string = "abc";
$a = new InputEvent($string);

$input = &$a->getInput();

$input .= "def";

echo $a->getInput();
```